# Erlang "unbound variable" when calling a function

Tags: erlang

I am trying to pass an integer parameter N to `cake` and return a list of size N of the square of 2 (for the sake of example). e.g. bakery:cake(3) => [4,4,4]

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
-module(bakery).
-export([cake/1]).

Foo = fun(X) -> X * X end.

cake(0) -> [];
cake(N) when N > 0 -> [ Foo(2) | cake(N-1) ].
```

When I compile the code `c(bakery).` in erl however, I get the following error trace:

```
bakery.erl:4:  syntax error before: Foo
bakery.erl:7:  variable 'Foo' is unbound
error
```

I am still getting used to anonymous functions and erlang in general coming an object-oriented world. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each Erlang module, as described [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html), should consist of a sequence of attributes and function declarations, each terminated by period (.)

But this line:

```
Foo = fun(X) -> X * X end.
```

... is neither and should be written as follows instead:

```
foo(X) -> X * X.
```

`foo` is lowercase here, because this line is a [function declaration](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html), where function name should be an [atom](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id67764).

So in the end your module will look like this:

```
-module(bakery).
-export([cake/1]).

foo(X) -> X * X.

cake(0) -> [];
cake(N) when N > 0 -> [ foo(2) | cake(N-1) ].
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous solution is correct, but you can resolve the problem with this code too:

```
-module(bakery).
-export([cake/1]).

cake(0) -> [];
cake(N) when N > 0 ->
   Foo = fun(X) -> X * X end,
   [ Foo(2) | cake(N-1) ].
```

Regards.