# Top level assignment

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

I was trying to create a function using a higher-order function in Erlang. To my surprisement, this seems to not be okay. Here's a simplified example of the error I'm getting.

```
-module(test).
-export([main/0]).

X = 1.

main() ->
    io:format("~p~n", [X]).
```

And in erl:

```
> c(test).
test.erl:4: syntax error before: X
test.erl:7: variable 'X' is unbound
error
```

Do you have any idea what could be done to circumvent this?

Comment: If you're wondering, I have a line like this in the real project: `EntityBehavior = behaviorOf(fun entityBehaviorGroup/1, fun entityNehavior/1).`

Comment: A related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770042/variable-in-erlang/25775401#25775401

Comment: @zxq9 That makes my question kind of useless, should I delete it?

Comment: If you want it purged, then sure -- but I don't think you can with an accepted answer (it would screw Steve, so I think the system prevents it). You may instead want to mark it as a duplicate if you are able. In any case, I'm glad you have a firm understanding of the answer to your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no global variables in Erlang. You can use a function instead, like this for example:

```
-module(test).
-export([main/0]).

x() ->
    1.

main() ->
    io:format("~p~n", [x()]).
```

For something as simple as a literal `1` you could also define a preprocessor macro, like this:

```
-define(X, 1).

main() ->
    io:format("~p~n", [?X]).
```

but given that your question mentions higher-order functions, you probably don't want to use the preprocessor.

Comment: Thought this might be the case, but wanted to make sure.  Thanks.